# mp3wrap file not playable

Tags: mp3

I combined six MP3 files, with filenames starting with `0`, into one MP3 with the following command under Debian Wheezy:

```
$ mp3wrap -v output.mp3 0*
```

Using `file` on `output.mp3` confirmed that it was an MP3 file. The file plays using `mocp`, but will not play on a Samsung Galaxy S3 with either the built-in player or an external player. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with files merged with `mp3wrap` on my Nexus. The only working solution, I found is to use `ffmpeg` as a merge tool.

## How to

This will concatenate two mp3 files, and the resulting metadata will be that of the first file:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:file1.mp3|file2.mp3" -acodec copy output.mp3
```

This is because, for ffmpeg, the whole "concat:" part is a single "input file", and its metadata will be of the first concatenated file. If you want to use metadata from the second file instead, you have to add it as a dummy input file and map its metadata to that of the output:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:file1.mp3|file2.mp3" -i file2.mp3 -acodec copy test.mp3 -map_metadata 0:1
```

If you want to construct your metadata from the two metadatas, you'll have to do it by hand. You can dump a file's metadata with

```
ffmpeg -i file1.mp3 -f ffmetadata file1.metadata
```

After dumping both metadatas and constructing new metadata, you can add it to the output file with `-metadata`, and you can disable metadata copying by setting a `-map_metadata` mapping from a negative input file number. This sets a name value and no other metadata:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:file1.mp3|file2.mp3" -acodec copy -metadata "title=Some Song" test.mp3 -map_metadata 0:-1
```

*Above instructions were copied from [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/314245/270746) answer from a similar question*

Answer (score 0):

I use MP3Diags to fix the tags after joining the files with mp3wrap, but I'm not able to check that repaired MP3 tags will allow the Samsung Galaxy S3 to play the file, as I do not have one to test with.

Comment: Thanks, but there was no reason to believe that the tags were the problem.